# Shall I say "need not" or "need none"?

Tags: grammar

> I need sleep, whereas you seem to need not. (self-made)

When I first say “need”, I use it not as a modal verb, but an ordinary verb. So in the second part of the sentence the “need” is still an ordinary verb. It seems only modal verbs or auxiliary verbs can use the structure like “verb+ not” instead of “do/does not + verb?  Therefore I cannot say “you seem to need not” here, and better say “you seem to need none”?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it may at best be asked on ELL.

Comment: You may be already aware of [ell.se]

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems with your sentence.

The first problem is not that the verb *need* is modal, but that *sleep* is a noun in the first clause. When you say *need not*, you are using elision in a way that requires a verb in the first sentence. Even if you use a non-modal verb in this construction, it's still wrong:

> *I want sleep, but you don't want to.

Since *sleep* is a noun, you are correct that you can fix it by using the pronoun *none*.

> I need sleep, but you need none.

For parallelism with the modal and non-modal verb *need*, you could try:

> *I need to sleep, whereas you seem to need not.

This isn't wrong because of the parallelism; it's wrong because "whereas you seem to need not" is using a modal verb need in a way you can't use modal verbs. You can't say "to ⟨modal⟩".

> *I can go, whereas you seem to can not.

Here, you have to replace the modal with the non-modal equivalent:

> I can go, whereas you seem not to be able to.
>   I need to sleep, whereas you seem not to need to.

Now, let's try for parallelism between modal and non-modal *need* without any of the other problems:

> I need to attend this meeting, but you needn't.

This sounds fine to me.

Comment: I need sleep but you seem not to.